# set the ip of the mesos master on a slave

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I have three mesos slave nodes and one master on 10.14.56.157, 10.14.56.159 and 10.14.56.160 and 10.14.56.156 respectively. The names of the machines are worker1, worker2, worker3 and master.

I managed to set up the mesos cluster correctly (I believe). The web UI on 10.0.0.4:5050 shows all the three slaves. Then I'm running a spark shell on the cluster. Everything initially works fine: shell starts, UI shows a new framework started etc. Then I'm trying to run a simple test:

```
val numbers = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000000, 1000)
```

which works fine and then

```
numbers.count
```

Of course this is when spark actually does some work. So it starts the tasks, sends it to slaves (I can see it in the logs) but then none of the tasks completes (status: LOST). Spark retries the tasks up to 4 times and eventually gives up. I looked into the logs on the slave machines (the sandbox link in the UI) and I get the following output:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0227 13:47:59.842319 17015 fetcher.cpp:76] Fetching URI '/home/user01/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop1.tgz'
I0227 13:47:59.842658 17015 fetcher.cpp:179] Copying resource from '/home/user01/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop1.tgz' to '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1/frameworks/20150227-132220-2620919306-5050-30420-0001/executors/20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1/runs/1978f267-cb47-4a6c-bd1f-69e99c00ae13'
I0227 13:48:09.896682 17015 fetcher.cpp:64] Extracted resource '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1/frameworks/20150227-132220-2620919306-5050-30420-0001/executors/20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1/runs/1978f267-cb47-4a6c-bd1f-69e99c00ae13/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop1.tgz' into '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1/frameworks/20150227-132220-2620919306-5050-30420-0001/executors/20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1/runs/1978f267-cb47-4a6c-bd1f-69e99c00ae13'
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/02/27 13:48:11 INFO MesosExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
I0227 13:48:11.493357 17124 exec.cpp:132] Version: 0.20.1
I0227 13:48:11.496057 17142 exec.cpp:206] Executor registered on slave 20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1
15/02/27 13:48:11 INFO MesosExecutorBackend: Registered with Mesos as executor ID 20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1 with 1 cpus
15/02/27 13:48:11 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 20150226-160235-2620919306-5050-14323-1 on host 10.14.56.160
15/02/27 13:48:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: user01
15/02/27 13:48:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: user01
15/02/27 13:48:11 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(user01); users with modify permissions: Set(user01)
15/02/27 13:48:12 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/02/27 13:48:12 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/02/27 13:48:12 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@10.14.56.160:42869]
15/02/27 13:48:12 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkExecutor' on port 42869.
15/02/27 13:48:12 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to MapOutputTracker: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@master:48886/user/MapOutputTracker
15/02/27 13:48:12 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@master:48886]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: master: Name or service not known
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for:       ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkDriver@master:48886/), Path(/user/MapOutputTracker)]
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:267)
    at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:508)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:541)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:531)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:87)
    at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.postStop(Endpoint.scala:561)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPostStop(Actor.scala:475)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundPostStop(Endpoint.scala:415)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:210)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" I0227 13:48:12.364940 17142 exec.cpp:413] Deactivating the executor libprocess
```

The line where the error occurs says: 
    Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@master:48886]

It seems to me that the slave cannot resolve the name master to the master's IP. Is that correct? If so how to change it to the actual IP. If not, how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: how are you submitting the job to the Mesos cluster?>

Comment: I'm running the shell here. So I only specify the master when I start the shell

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you type `ping master` on one of the slave machines? If that fails, that's your problem, and you could fix it by adding a line to each slave's `/etc/hosts` file pointing `master` to the correct IP.

You could also try setting `spark.driver.host` to its IP when launching the spark driver, to change what "host" it advertises itself as.

Comment: Hey Adam, they all see each other. What I ended up doing was to change /etc/hosts so that all names (master, worker1, worker2, worker3) are resolved. So it works, but I feel like it's a hack to do it this way. Also I added the host option to the master initialization script but it didn't help.

Comment: Are any of the scheduler/executor/tasks or master/slave running inside VMs or docker containers that have different internal vs. external IPs? If so, you may also try setting the LIBPROCESS_IP (or --ip) to the externally visible IP.